# Why is my timer function having irregular intervals?

Tags: swift, xcode, loops, timer

I have attached my code for you to see.

What I want to achieve:

- Timer repeats 5 times
- Hardcoded time of 10s
- the display of a number (i) reduces by 1 with each iteration

What happens:

- i goes straight to 1
- countdown goes something like 5, 0, -2, -4, -8, -13 NOT 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 then repeat

  ```
    var timer = Timer()
    var i = 5
    // number of repeats is 5
    var time = 10
    // timer is 10s


   class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var displayTime: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var displayI: UILabel!

  @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {
    for _ in 1...5 {
        displayI.text = String(i)
        countdown()
        i -= 1
    }
  }

   func countdown() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(Action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   }

   @objc func Action() {
    time -= 1
    displayTime.text = String(time)
    if time == 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
  ```

  }

Can anyone help?
(I also tried a repeat while loop where it repeats while (i >= 1) so it should stop when i=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that loops (any kind) runs very quickly. Your `for _ in 1...5` loop completes before the first call to `Action` even starts. This is because `countdown()` completes almost immediately, *not* after the timer it creates has been `invalidate`d.

When you create a timer, it runs *asynchronously* to the rest of your code. So the line immediately after `countdown()` is not when the timer will end. The line in the `if time == 0` statement *is*.

<sub>Note that even if the timer were synchronous, your code wouldn't have worked because you didn't reset `time` to 10 when each timer ends.</sub>

Anyway, the five timers will decrement `time` almost at the same time, and depending on when the UI refreshes, you will see that `time` has decremented a different amount.

You seem to just want to count from 10 to 0 five times. You can do this with just one timer:

```
@objc func Action() {
  time -= 1
  displayTime.text = String(time)
  if time == 0 {
    i -= 1
    time = 11
  }
  if i == 0 {
      timer.invalidate()
  }
}

@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {
  countdown()
}
```

`i` counts how many times this is, and `time` counts the number to display.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explaination! It's sorted it out perfectly